# Multiple default parameter values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to select multiple default values for my report parameter.

The "Available Values" come from a dataset called Color, which has Color_Code and Color_Name columns. There are total of 10 colors in the table.

I would like to use "Color_Code" $1, $2, and $3 as my default values.

I tried using "Specific Values" option in Default Values section, but the report didn't automatically select the three colors.

Comment: the color code is $1, $2, and $3?

Comment: Yes (it's an example).